# Error in code in ionic2/angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2

Here, I am getting error in following code below indicated as I want to return promise but getting error in returning promise. How to returning promise?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { UsersPage } from '../users/users';
import { ShopPage } from '../shop/shop';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
usrPage = UsersPage;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}
  onGoToUsers(){
    this.navCtrl.push(this.usrPage)
    .catch((error)=> console.log('Access Denied, Argument was' + error));
  }

  ionViewCanLeave(): boolean | Promise<void> {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(()=>{
        resolve()
      }, 1000);
    });
    return promise;   // the line is producing error in returning promise.
  }

}
```

Comment: What's the actual error? What's even the question?

Comment: @Lazar, as I mentioned above, it is producing error in returning promise .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `ionViewCanLeave(): boolean | Promise<void> {`

to this.

`ionViewCanLeave(): boolean | Promise<any> {`

Essentially, `Promise<void>` is not equal to `Promise` in your case. (which you return). Thus change the `<T>` of the promise to use `any` as the generic value.

The reason `void` is not equal to `any` is that `void` essentially means an absence of a type whereas `any` means any type. `undefined` and `null` can be assigned to a `void` type variable.

The line `const promise = new Promise...` declares the variable type implicitly as you do not give the type after the `promise` declaration, so it assumes it to be `Promise<any>`. 
Thus, if you would write `const promise: Promise<void>` and it would also work.

Another way this could work would be to return the `Promise` directly like this: (Perhaps the tutorial you followed showed the function like this?)

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   //
});
```

Since this is a return statement it would tell the typescript compiler to implicitly assume the correct return type that is `Promise<void>` instead of `Promise<any>` since that happens when you assign this Promise to a typeless `const promise`.

Hope I was able to shed some light. Read more about typescript types from [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html).

Comment: Thanks, but the same piece of code that i mentioned above run without any error on a tutorial, can't figure why it produced error in my case.

Comment: Editing my answer to shed more light.